# How to enable rainbow brackets in Cursive IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

I use [Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com) in IDEA community edition. It displays all brackets in black color which is lead to a problem of catching by eyes the edges of expression.

Does rainbow brackets support by Cursive? 
If yes, how to enable it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're on by default. Somehow, I've used Cursive for almost 2 years now, and can't think if I've actually had them or not. Poke around File->Settings. Cursive has settings in there.

Comment: It is not by default, but your comment helped me to find the option in the IDE settings. I just thought that it has to be supported by Cursive, not IDEA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the option through `Idea -> Preferences` search bar
[image: Rainbow]